# Running awk in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, awk, apache-kafka, logstash

I do not have the ability to do much but receive unstructured syslogs from Kafka which have been produced with logstash.

When I attach logstash as a consumer, these syslogs are all over the place and contain half a dozen patterns or more which very wildly. This is something more fitting to be run somehow streamed with an awk filter since the programmatic approach to passing incoming messages is actually quite sttisghtforward with such a tool.

Does anyone have any input on how one could attach a consumer to a Kafka topic and procure incoming logs and ship these logs in am intelligent way towards an elasticsearch clister?

Comment: did you tried Kafka input plugin in Logstash?

Comment: I use the kafka input plugin, yes. However what I want to do is 
a. parse the logs with awk before logstash consumes from kafka. (How would be a good way to implement this continually?) 
b. parse the logs with awk in logstash's filter block (with kafka input plugin?)

Comment: Logstash should offer a way to add filter plugins where you can run any function you want

Comment: How so? Do you know?

Comment: Here's one example I found - https://github.com/hahni8090/logstash-filter-commands

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grok expressions in your LOGSTASH config to parse the logs https://logz.io/blog/logstash-grok/ . This should allow you to filter, transform or drop data.

Or use something like CRIBL in between KAFKA and ELASTIC https://docs.cribl.io/stream/about/

Note on the CRIBL page how under sources KAFKA is one of the supported sources and ELASTIC is one of the supported destinations. This should allow to transform your data before ingesting it into ELASTIC.

Comment: I am hoping to avoid using grok expressions since the patterns vary too much and it's unwieldy in comparison to something like awk.